# For how long 12.04 LTS will be supported ? 5 or 3 years?

Tags: release-management

Hey everyone today my friend call me and he told me that 12.04LTS it will be support for 3 years is that correct ? because i think it will be supported for 5 years, i am not sure but i heard from different person told me that 12.04 will be supported for 5 , so please someone tell me 5 OR 3 years ?
i am speaking about desktop NOT server version

thanks

Comment: 5 years. LTS releases were traditionally supported for three years on the desktop and five years on the server. However with the release of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, desktop support for LTS releases was extended to five years. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)

Answer (score 7):

Canonical will provide security updates for 12.04 LTS through April 2017 on the desktop and server. That's five years total from release.

[image]

You can read about Canonical's support plan [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS/).